# Need code for extracting useable data from IMDB text files with R

Tags: r

Does anyone have any code handy that extracts data from the downloadable imdb text files and transposes them into a more useable format? The text files are not in an immediately useable format and are somewhat problematic to convert. For example, the business.list file looks like this for each movie, a sort of multiple tags (different tags and number of each tag) for each moive (some with less tags, some with more tags).

I am looking for a way to change these files into a data frame.

---

MV: The Clearing (2004)

GR: USD 5,763,875 (USA) (10 October 2004) 
GR: USD 5,761,124 (USA) (3 October 2004)

OW: USD 618,674 (USA) (4 July 2004) (56 screens)

SD: 23 September 2002 - November 2002

WG: USD 1,350 (USA) (10 October 2004) (2 screens)

---

More information is here: http://www.imdb.com/interfaces

In the mean time, I am going to poke around with some of the other interfaces such as the text unix one.

Comment: All I have done so far is look into reading the data into a single column data frame of strings and then looping through that column, parsing the strings as needed and putting the results into a new pivoted data frame and write that tole file. It's just messy and time consuming. If someone has done it before...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [IMDB  API](http://imdbapi.com/) and the RCurl and XML packages to get structured data from the site.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid web scraping and API work, but web research and chatting with some of my peers, seems to be pushing me this way.

Comment: Wow. That's super simple, although the API is missing box office which is important for my needs (and in the above file). I shall take a look at this API and perhaps use the results (movie I'd) to pull up the actual web page and grab box office there...

Answer (score 1):

It's not R, but [imdbpy](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/) is a python library that does exactly that.